# django facebook how to redirect back to previous page

Tags: django, django-facebook

I am using the django facebook app, how do I get the user redirected back to previous page after login ?

I tried to use the "next" hidden input box, but that did not work .

```
<input type = "hidden" name = "next" value = "{{ request.GET.next }}" />
```

Comment: Are you using django-social? What facebook app are you using where did you get it from? You should check its documentation and or source code.

Comment: https://github.com/tschellenbach/Django-facebook

Answer (score 0):

from the [Django-facebook docs](http://django-facebook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/registration_backend.html):

In settings.py you can set

`FACEBOOK_LOGIN_DEFAULT_REDIRECT = "/whatever/"`

to change the default-redirect.

**edit**

Another way is to subclass the facebook-app's custom backend like so (excerpt from the docs):

```
from django_facebook.registration_backends import FacebookRegistrationBackend

class CustomBackend(FacebookRegistrationBackend):
    def post_connect(action):
        # go as crazy as you want, just be sure to return a response
        response = HttpRedirect('/something/')
        if action is CONNECT_ACTIONS.LOGIN:
            response = HttpRedirect('/')
        return response
```

`post_connect` handles the redirect after connecting.

Comment: can you do that without using settings.py? as a post for example?

Comment: Can I pass the page I want it redirect to via post and that gets passed back when we get back from facebook back to the site? Basically, if they login via facebook on page A, i want to pass page A's url to Facebook and then back to the site so that the user gets redirected back to page A when he returns back to the site.